# Autodesk forge markup 3D error TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autodesk-forge

I have implemented Autodesk Forge's Markup 3D into my sample model I have imported all the necessary and required JavaScript files but I get an Error `TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function`. I'm struck with this and I'm not able to rectify the error. I have tried many of the solutions that has been given on the internet but I'm not even close to rectify the issue.
     I have referred the code from the website.
 http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/playing-with-the-new-view-data-markup-api.html

any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't tooltip part of jquery UI? Did you include it?

Comment: Yes, I have included the very recent version of it @Chris

Comment: It is possible that the code is trying to use it before it finished loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.tooltip()` is a [bootstrap plugin](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp), so you need to include bootstrap to your app as well or simply remove the `$.tooltip` calls. Btw - I assume you are talking about Markup 2D as the link suggest, not my custom extension [Markup 3D](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/04/markup3d-sample-for-view-data-api.html).